Mouse lag in Remote Desktop (App Store version) vs no lag in old client mstsc
I have Windows 11 VM installed under Hyper-V with Enhanced Session enabled.
When I use this VM to RDP to other Windows guests via the old client, mstsc, the experience is seamless. When RDPing via the MS Store app, there is a clear lag that looks similar to the lag of Virtualbox when Guest additions are not installed. The lag persists whether it's set to full screen, or a custom resolution.
I'd prefer the Store App version of the RDP Client because it has dynamic resolution adjustment.
